# Check if the Calendar date is a sunday

Tags: java, date, calendar

I am trying to figure out how to make my program count the number of Sundays in a week.

I have tried the following thing:

```
if (date.DAY_OF_WEEK == date.SUNDAY) {
    System.out.println("Sunday!");
}
```

Yet it does not seem to work?

When I try to `System.out.Println the date.DAY_OF_WEEK` I get: `7`

Does anyone know how I can check if the current calendar date is Sunday?

**UPDATE FOR MORE INFORMATION**

1. firt of all the date.DAY_OF_WEEK is a Calendar object!
2. i made sure to set the Calendar object `date` to a sunday

The system out print where i get 7 is what it returns to me when i try to run `date.DAY_OF_MONTH` even if the day it set to a sunday

**2nd UPDATE TO ALEX**

This is more or less my code

```
Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();

    startDate.set(2012, 12, 02);
    if (startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
        System.out.println("true");
    }else {
        System.out.println("FALSE");
    }
```

Comment: `numberOfSundaysInAWeek = 1`

Comment: using date is depreciated. you should go with the calendar class.

Comment: Sorry i didnt make it clear the date.DAY_OF_WEEK is a Calendar object

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = ...;
if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
    System.out.println("Sunday!");
}
```

`Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK` always equals to `7` no matter what instance of `Calendar` you are using ([see this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)), it is a constant created to be used with the `Calendar.get()` method to retrieve the correct value.

It is the call to `Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)` that will return the real day of week. Besides, you will find useful values in the `Calendar` class like `Calendar.SUNDAY` (and the other days and months) in order for you to be more explicit in your code and avoid errors like `JANUARY` being equal to `0`.

**Edit**

Like I said, the `Calendar` class does contains useful constants for you to use. There is no month number `12` they start at `0` (see above), so `DECEMBER` is month number `11` in the Java Date handling.

```
Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
startDate.set(2012, Calendar.DECEMBER, 02);
if (startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
    System.out.println("true");
} else {
    System.out.println("FALSE");
}
```

Will print `true` of course.

Comment: This:

  Calendar cal = startDate;
  System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)== Calendar.SUNDAY); 

is false

Comment: in that example a new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("02/12/2012") is added where i use a Date Object to set my Calendar could this be the problem?

Comment: Please show the complete code so that I can see what is going on.

Comment: Because this does not seem to work: if (startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) { System.out.println("true"); }

Comment: What does `System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(startDate.getTime()));` print out?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20403/discussion-between-marc-rasmussen-and-alex)

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @Basil Bourque that's correct...the downside though is that  java.time requires a project minimum api 26....Bad luck for us working with lower api requirements...By the way, the answer given by Alex worked fine for me...just remember to set the fields of the same calendar you're trying to use when invoke the cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) method....

Comment: @Ramiro In the latest version of tooling, [desugaring  makes available to earlier Android many of the Java 8 APIs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). This includes a large subset of *java.time*. If that desugaring does not prove sufficient, use the *ThreeTenABP* library to back-port most of *java.time* to early Android. See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55466522/642706) for links. So there is no need to ever use those terrible legacy date-time classes.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** the [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) project is now in maintenance mode. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55466522/1288408) if you don't have to work with legacy code.

---

If you have to work with date or time a lot, you might want to try using [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

Your code would look something like this:

```
LocalDate startDate = new LocalDate(2012, 12, 2);
int day = startDate.dayOfWeek().get();   // gets the day of the week as integer

if (DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY == day) {
    System.out.println("It's a Sunday!");
}
```

You can also get a text string from `dayOfWeek()`:

```
String dayText = startDate.dayOfWeek().getAsText();
```

will return the string "Sunday".

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Yes, I know. I'll leave this answer for users working with legacy code. Your answer is great, I'll upvote and link to it from mine. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
boolean todayIsSunday = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).getDayOfWeek().equals( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ;
```

## java.time

The other Answers are outdated. The modern approach uses *java.time* classes.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument. If critical, confirm the zone with your user.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). Ditto for [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) & [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

## `DayOfWeek`

For any `LocalDate`, you can obtain its day-of-week as a [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) object. The `DayOfWeek` enum automatically instantiates seven objects, one for each day of the week.

```
boolean isSunday = ld.getDayOfWeek().equals( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ;
```

## One Sunday per week

> count the number of Sundays in a week.

That would be 1, always one Sunday per week.

If your goal is finding the next Sunday, use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) defined in [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class.

```
TemporalAdjuster ta = TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ;
LocalDate nextOrSameSunday = ld.with( ta ) ;
```

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image]