# i'm trying to group the leads created by their status and group them by the days of the week created from Monday to Saturday using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, endpoint

I'm supposed to get the leads created from Microsoft SQL server database by their status and the day they are created to display the information on a graph that summarizes the leads created from Monday to Saturday. below is the my code and a screenshot of the graph I'm using to display the data

```
@Override
public Response<Map<String, Collection<LeadsDashboard>>getLeadsDashboards(){
    Response<Map<String, Collection<LeadsDashboard>>response = new Response<>();

    User user = userRepository.getById(auditorAware.getCurrentAuditor().get().getId());
    List<Leadleads = leadRepository.findAll(user.getCompany().getId());
    Collection<LeadsDashboardunqualifiedClosed = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] unqualifiedClosedi = new int[6];
    AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    Collection<LeadsDashboardunqualifiedOpen = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] unqualifiedOpeni = new int[6];
    AtomicInteger counter2 = new AtomicInteger();
    Collection<LeadsDashboardnewLeads = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] newLeadsi = new int[6];
    AtomicInteger counter3 = new AtomicInteger();
    Collection<LeadsDashboardclosedLeads = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] closedLeadi = new int[6];
    AtomicInteger counter4 = new AtomicInteger();
    Collection<LeadsDashboardrejectedLeads = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] rejectedLeadsi = new int[6];
    AtomicInteger counter5 = new AtomicInteger();
    Collection<LeadsDashboardapprovedLeads = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] approvedLeadsi = new int[6];
    AtomicInteger counter6 = new AtomicInteger();
    Collection<LeadsDashboardopenLeads = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] openLeadsi = new int[6];
    AtomicInteger counter7 = new AtomicInteger();
    
    leads.forEach(lead ->{
        LeadsDashboard leadsDashboard = new LeadsDashboard();
        leadsDashboard.setStatus(lead.getStatus());
        if(lead.getStatus().equals(Statuses.UNQUALIFIED_CLOSED.getStatus())){
            // leadsDashboard.setCount(unqualifiedClosed.size() + 1);
            unqualifiedClosedi[counter.getAndIncrement()] = unqualifiedClosedi[counter.get()] + 1;
            leadsDashboard.setCount(unqualifiedClosedi);
            unqualifiedClosed.add(leadsDashboard);
        }
        if(lead.getStatus().equals(Statuses.UNQUALIFIED_OPEN.getStatus())){
            // leadsDashboard.setCount(unqualifiedOpen.size() + 1);
            unqualifiedOpeni[counter2.getAndIncrement()] = unqualifiedOpeni[counter2.get()] + 1;
            leadsDashboard.setCount(unqualifiedOpeni);
            unqualifiedOpen.add(leadsDashboard);
        }
        if(lead.getStatus().equals(Statuses.NEW.getStatus())){
            // leadsDashboard.setCount(newLeads.size() + 1);
            newLeadsi[counter3.getAndIncrement()] = newLeadsi[counter3.get()] + 1;
            leadsDashboard.setCount(newLeadsi);
            newLeads.add(leadsDashboard);
        }
        if(lead.getStatus().equals(Statuses.CLOSED.getStatus())){
            // leadsDashboard.setCount(closedLeads.size() + 1);
            closedLeadi[counter4.getAndIncrement()] = closedLeadi[counter2.get()] + 1;
            leadsDashboard.setCount(closedLeadi);
            closedLeads.add(leadsDashboard);
        }
        if(lead.getStatus().equals(Statuses.REJECT.getStatus())){
            //  leadsDashboard.setCount(rejectedLeads.size() + 1);
            rejectedLeadsi[counter5.getAndIncrement()] = rejectedLeadsi[counter5.get()] + 1;
            leadsDashboard.setCount(rejectedLeadsi);
            rejectedLeads.add(leadsDashboard);
        }
        if(lead.getStatus().equals(Statuses.APPROVED.getStatus())){
            //  leadsDashboard.setCount(approvedLeads.size() + 1);
            approvedLeadsi[counter6.getAndIncrement()] = approvedLeadsi[counter6.get()] + 1;
            leadsDashboard.setCount(approvedLeadsi);
            approvedLeads.add(leadsDashboard);
        }
        if(lead.getStatus().equals(Statuses.OPEN.getStatus())){
            //  leadsDashboard.setCount(qualifiedLeads.size() + 1);
            openLeadsi[counter7.getAndIncrement()] = openLeadsi[counter7.get()] + 1;
            leadsDashboard.setCount(openLeadsi);
            openLeads.add(leadsDashboard);
        }
    });

    Map<String, Collection<LeadsDashboard>resMap = new HashMap<>();
    resMap.put("approvedLeads", approvedLeads);
    resMap.put("rejectedLeads", rejectedLeads);
    resMap.put("closedLeads", closedLeads);
    resMap.put("newLeads", newLeads);
    resMap.put("openLeads", openLeads);
    resMap.put("unqualifiedOpen", unqualifiedOpen);
    resMap.put("unqualifiedClose", unqualifiedClosed);

    response.setBody(resMap);

    return response;
}
```

[graph that is supposed to display the leads created weekly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFezb.jpg)

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure on how to group the leads by the day created

Comment: so far i have grouped them by their status

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647422/check-if-the-calendar-date-is-a-sunday

You can use this link to do the **days of the week created** base comparison. PS: In the status-based comparison will there be a need to check other statuses if the status matches with any one of the expected statuses (eg; `UNQUALIFIED_OPEN`) ? If not you can go with `if and else if`.

Comment: yes there is a need to check other statuses so as to group the leads according to which status they are currently in

Comment: @Christianjire did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the sample project I created for testing:

```java
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<Lead> leads = Arrays.stream(Status.values()).flatMap(status ->
                        IntStream.range(0, 10)
                                .mapToObj(i -> new Lead(status, LocalDate.now().minusDays(RandomUtils.nextInt(0, 7)))))
                .toList();

        final Map<Status, Map<LocalDate, Long>> groupedByStatusAndDate =
                leads.stream().collect(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(Lead::getStatus,
                                Collectors.groupingBy(Lead::getDate, Collectors.counting())));

        groupedByStatusAndDate.forEach((status, map) -> {
            System.out.println("-- " + status + " --");
            map.forEach((date, count) -> System.out.println(date + ": " + count));
        });
    }

    public static class Lead {

       private final Status status;
       private final LocalDate date;

        public Lead(Status status, LocalDate date) {
            this.status = status;
            this.date = date;
        }

        public Status getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public LocalDate getDate() {
            return date;
        }

    }

    public enum Status {
        UNQUALIFIED_CLOSED,
        UNQUALIFIED_OPEN,
        NEW,
        CLOSED,
        REJECT,
        APPROVED,
        OPEN
    }
```

It outputs the following:

```
-- REJECT --
2022-12-14: 3
2022-12-12: 2
2022-12-11: 2
2022-12-09: 1
2022-12-08: 2

-- UNQUALIFIED_OPEN --
2022-12-14: 2
2022-12-12: 1
2022-12-11: 2
2022-12-10: 1
2022-12-09: 2
2022-12-08: 2

-- CLOSED --
2022-12-14: 2
2022-12-13: 1
2022-12-12: 1
2022-12-11: 1
2022-12-10: 2
2022-12-09: 2
2022-12-08: 1

-- UNQUALIFIED_CLOSED --
2022-12-13: 3
2022-12-12: 2
2022-12-10: 2
2022-12-09: 3

-- NEW --
2022-12-14: 2
2022-12-13: 3
2022-12-12: 1
2022-12-11: 1
2022-12-10: 2
2022-12-08: 1

-- OPEN --
2022-12-13: 2
2022-12-12: 1
2022-12-11: 3
2022-12-10: 1
2022-12-09: 2
2022-12-08: 1

-- APPROVED --
2022-12-14: 1
2022-12-13: 1
2022-12-12: 2
2022-12-11: 1
2022-12-10: 2
2022-12-09: 1
2022-12-08: 2
```

Maybe a good read for you: [Baeldung guide to `groupingBy`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector)